# PointLight won't illuminate anything

Tags: javascript, three.js

*EDIT:*
*Now I have two barebone examples using first MeshBasicMaterial and second MeshLambertMaterial:*

*[PointLight_sucks__MeshBasicMaterial.html](http://myinnerouterworldsimulator.neocities.org/PointLight_sucks__MeshBasicMaterial.html)*

*[PointLight_sucks__MeshLambertMaterial.html](http://myinnerouterworldsimulator.neocities.org/PointLight_sucks__MeshLambertMaterial.html)*

*both uses PointLight's but the LambertMaterial geometry isn't illuminated t all (but there seems to be small blinking dots on the screen?).*

---

I have a geometry made with `MeshBasicMaterial`. Somehow it illuminates itself:

[image]

I also have a `PointLight`:

```
light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xaaaaaa );
light.position.set = new THREE.Vector3(-400, 0, 0);
makeScene.scene.add( light );
```

but it has no effect on the scene. I want the scene to only be illuminated by the `PointLight`.

I have tried various other materials for my geometry, such as MeshPhongMaterial, MeshNormalMaterial, MeshLambertMaterial and MeshFaceMaterial.

This is how I apply the `MeshBasicMaterial`:

```
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(aGeometry, material);
```

I suspect there might be something wrong with my `PointLight`. How do I verify that `PointLight` is correctly applied to the scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()` is not affected by light. Change it to `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial()` or `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()`

**EDIT:**

In addition `THREE.PointLight()` does not affect `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()` as per http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Lights/PointLight.

As per the `PointLight()` and the interaction with `MeshLambertMaterial()` you have an error in your code:
The lines

```
light1.position.set = new THREE.Vector3(0, -120, 150);
light2.position.set = new THREE.Vector3(0,  120, 150);
```

should be

```
light1.position.set (0, -120, 150);
light2.position.set (0,  120, 150);
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle? Your light is on the negative x-axis. Is that side of your mesh brighter?

Comment: Thanks :D  I can give you your bounty when 11 hours has passed

Answer (score 0):

MeshBasicMaterial is not affected by light, use other material type as suggested by gaitat.

It happens to me quite often that light is too small to be noticeable or it is placed too far from the mesh I want to illuminate. Maybe this is your case too.