# DirectioanlLight Doesn't work in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, light

I try to add light in Three.js but when I update display, light doesn't affect on my cilinder I literally copy pasted the source code from Three.js docs [Three.js](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/DirectionalLight)
but it doesnt work,

this is my code

```js
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.126.1";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
//scene and camera set up
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

//renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(devicePixelRatio);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
//Orbitcontrols
new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
camera.position.z = 5;

//setting up cilinder 
const geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 1.4, 2, .6, 10 )
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x327322} )
const cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material )
scene.add( cylinder )

//Light Part
const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.1);
light.position.set(0, 0, 1)
scene.add(light)

const animate = () => {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate()
```

You can also check how it works on codepen  **[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/callmenikk/pen/jOmqagG)**

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29415263/pointlight-wont-illuminate-anything

Comment: he uses pointlight but I use DirectionalLight also I tried his version but didnt fixed my issue

Comment: Read the first sentence of the answer in the above link.

Comment: Oppss... Sorry my bad, you were right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found issue in by code, I use `MeshBasicMaterial()`, which doesn't react light, I should use `MeshPhongMaterial()`